# Are there any difference between word 2010 and 2016 about product key?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, product-key

I have both word 2010 and word 2016 and still have not activated the product key my all microsoft word. But, I still can edit with word 2010 without the product key but unlike word 2016 that i only can view the file. Can anyone explain this, please?

For word 2010, it says that `produck activation failed`.
For word 2016, it says that `Unlicensed product`

Comment: What's the problem? Just get licenses and activate the product you like. Paying two licenses is really too much, since they don't use the same product key.

Comment: I use both (and find Word 2010 better in general). They require separate product keys.

Answer (score 1):

Each Office suite has its own Product Key.

Office 2010 is older and has a product key (not a Microsoft Account).

Office 2016 is almost always by subscription for consumers (businesses use an Office 2016 Volume License). Office 2019 is the suite to get if you purchase outright.

The Product keys are definitely not the same.

All that said, you need licenses for both suites if you wish to run both and then activate both.

I find Office 2016 (including Word) does everything I need and our customers just use one suite.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Microsoft Office is not free product, the keys used to activate different Office versions are different (Except for the MAK key used for volume licensed versions of Office).

Even for the same retail release of Office, such as Office Home and Business 2010, Office Professioanl 2010, the keys used for them are different.

Besides, I do not suggest install different versions of Office apps on a same PC, as this behavior is more prone to some unexpected problems.